# Hereditary Cardinality and Rank

Tags: set-theory

For a set $x$, we have its *hereditary cardinality* defined as $$\textrm{hcard }x=|\textrm{trcl }x|\ ,$$
where trcl $x$ denotes the transitive closure of $x$. Meanwhile, the *rank* of a set is defined inductively: rank $\emptyset=0$, and $$\textrm{rank }x=\sup \{\textrm{rank } y+1:y\in x\}\ .$$
I'm trying to show that for an infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $$\forall x,\ \textrm{hcard }x<\kappa\rightarrow\textrm{rank }x<\kappa,$$
but my proofs using $\in$-induction so far don't seem to be getting anywhere. Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can show this by induction on $\kappa$. Suppose $\kappa$ is a successor cardinal; that is, $\kappa = \lambda^+$ for some $\lambda$. Then, if $hcard(x)<\kappa$, $|x|<\kappa$ and, by the induction hypothesis, $rank(y)<\kappa$, for $y\in x$. Since $\kappa$ is regular, it follows that $rank(x) <\kappa$. Now, suppose that $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal. Then, if $hcard(x)<\kappa$, there is $\kappa'<\kappa$ such that $hcard(x)<\kappa'$ and thus, by the induction hypothesis, $rank(x)<\kappa'<\kappa$.

Comment: Fantastic; thanks!

Comment: Is there a way around taking the regularity of successor cardinals for granted?

Comment: @CameronBuie I'm not sure how things would go in the absence of Choice.

Comment: I'm not sure where the assumption $rank(y) < \kappa$ is coming from. If anyone else is confused about this as well, there's a slightly different proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4408196/questions-about-the-induction-on-cardinals